# dynamic formGroup within formArray using formBuilder angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-forms

I have an array on my backend called media that stores several objects. It looks something like this:

```
"media": [
    {
        "srcId": null;
        "primary": false,
        "thumbs": {
            "default": null
        },
        "type": null,
        "raw": null
    }
]
```

My edit-component.ts for the loading this array into the form looks like this:

```
  media: this._fb.array([
    this._fb.group({
      srcId: new FormControl(this.existingMedia.srcId),
      type: new FormControl(this.existingMedia.type),
      raw: new FormControl(this.existingMedia.raw),
      primary: new FormControl(this.existingMedia.primary),
      thumbs: this._fb.group({
        default: new FormControl(this.existingMedia.thumb.default)
      })
    })
  ]),
```

Right now this will load the first object from that media array but not other media objects that could be in the array.
Is there a way to make the formBuilder group inside the formArray Media dynamic to the number of objects within the Media Array on the backend?

Any help/tips/suggestions would be much appreciated!

**Update**

In my ngOnInit I have:

```
  this.currentCard = selectedCurrentCard;
  for (let medias of this.currentCard.media){
    this.existingMedia = medias;
```

to iterate over my media array on the backend and

```
  const control = <FormArray>this.cardForm.controls['media'];
    control.push(this.initCurerntMedia());
```

with initCurrentMedia() looking like this:
**UPDATED initCurrentMedia()** this updated version worked when called in ngOnInit() Thanks to the help of @AJT_82

```
initCurrentMedia() {
    this.currentCard.media.forEach(media => {
      const control = <FormArray>this.cardForm.controls['media'];
      control.push(
        this._fb.group({
          srcId: new FormControl(media.srcId),
          type: new FormControl(media.type),
          raw: new FormControl(media.raw),
          primary: new FormControl(media.primary),
          thumbs: this._fb.group({
            default: new FormControl()
          })
        })
      )
    })
  }
```

To populate my form with current media. It is still only populating one object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to build the form

```ts
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
  media: this._fb.array([])
})
```

and then after response have been fetched set the values, so after getting the response you can call a method, let's say `setForm()`:

```ts
setForm() {
  this.media.forEach(x => {
    this.myForm.controls.media.push(
      this._fb.group({
        srcId: x.srcId,
        type: x.type,
        raw: x.raw,
        primary: x.primary,
        thumbs: this._fb.group({
          default: x.thumbs.default
        })        
      )
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I am following your logic @AJT_82 but I am getting a typescript error about property forEach not existing on type AbstractControl.

Comment: well `this.media` should point to the response and not the formarray. Seems you now are trying to iterate the formarray? The double naming is indeed a bit confusing, you should perhaps rename either :)

Comment: You are correct. I got this to work. I had to add in const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['media']; control.push(                           after that it is  working. Thank you @AJT_82!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it worked! Strange that the exact above code (without declaring variable for formarray as variable) didn't work as is, it has worked fine thus far for me. Well the most important thing is that it works now! Have a good one and Happy coding to you! :)